# Free alternatives to Smultron

Tags: macos

I was a long time user of Smultron. The app was freeware. Then the author decided to make the app paid, but the problem is that the app is now crap. A lot of bug, the app hangs constantly, a mess.

What other free/cheap alternatives do I have that can find/replace using regex and other stuff like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BBEdit has been the go-to text editor for macOS for decades. It has powerful grep search and replaces functionality, among other things.

It has a free mode and a paid mode, the latter mostly dealing with HTML editing.

Comment: Thanks I will check that out. I thought it was paid for all cases.